# Diagnosing root cause of garage door stall

Tags: garage-door

Sometimes the garage door will stop after moving two inches.  This event happens either when opening or closing.  The door is 13 years old.

When it stops the button is pushed to return it to the start position and one has to start again and hope it closes.  Usually it ends up opening on the second try.

What can be done to diagnose the root cause of the problem and hopefully apply corrective action to prevent the false start?  If you have observed and remedied this problem please state this in the response: thank you.

Comment: Have you tried re securing the lazer sensors? Is it possibke they are moving or being jostled on first start causing them to be thrown out of alignment effectively stopping the door?

Answer (score 3):

Garage doors have a counterbalance mechanism (usually springs).   You don't actually *lift* the door, only move it.  When lifting a garage door, you should only be fighting the friction of the rollers in tracks, and the inertia of the door's weight.

It's very important that you keep a door in tip-top condition.  The problem with a binding door is you end up forcing it.  *Forcing an already binding door makes it bind more.  And eventually damages the mechanism.*  Eventually the damage and spring force tears the door apart, killing someone.  This is serious business, don't turn your back on a damaged garage door.

### The power opener makes you blind

We have a factory with six huge doors on big 240V industrial power openers. Every door had serious problems.  *Nobody knew, because when an opener could no longer open the door, they just bought a bigger opener!*

**Unhook the opener.  Work it by hand.**

You'll find out in a right hurry where the problem is.  (or isn't).

There are about a dozen things that can go wrong with doors, and other sites have good checkout lists.  Just to name a few:

- door rollers wobbly (bearings failed)
- hinges sloppy due to excessive wear
- door very hard-moving because it's skewed/trammed (higher on one side) due to slipped drum
- unliftable due to counterbalance problem e.g. broken spring, cable problem or loose cable drum.
- drifting up/down due to spring too loose, too tight, or wrong spring
- door panels bent, e.g. from vehicle hit
- hinges badly aligned, causing binding

With our huge doors, each door had at least 3 of these.  Now they open so well we didn't bother reconnecting the openers.

These parts are mostly standardized and not particularly expensive.

Comment: A well-written response: please comment whether it was necessary to go to a specialty shop or a Home Depot (or similar) had the parts you replaced.

Comment: I could find them at my local family-owned building supply.  However I figured out what I needed, I mail ordered most of them because I could get better selection and grades of part, particularly 16ga. hinges.  I don't shop at HD or Lowes because they refuse to stock SKU's with low volume, and that leaves me 3 parts shy on almost every project.  Then I must go to the specialty shop who DOES stock everything, and why not just buy everything there.  Prices are comparable.  So now I support the shops that support me.